# Lisp: rudimentary object-oriented counter

Tags: object, lisp, closures, common-lisp, counter

I have to program an object-oriented counter. First the function make-object should instantiate the objects a and b with internal state 0. Then the 'methods' :inc, :dec and :res (increase, decrease, reset) are called. It should look like this:

```
> (setq a (make-object) b (make-object))
...
> (funcall a :inc)
1
> (funcall a :inc)
2
> (funcall a :res)
0
> (funcall a :dec)
-1
> (funcall b :inc)
1
```

My solution so far looks like this:

```
(defun make-object ()
  (let ((counter 0))
    (list #'(lambda () (incf counter))
          #'(lambda () (setf counter 0))
          #'(lambda () (decf counter)))))
```

With

```
(setq a (make-object) b (make-object))
```

I can instantiate a and b and the methods are called with

```
(funcall (first a))
(funcall (second b))
(funcall (third a))
```

I tried the following to call the methods with ":inc" instead of "first":

```
(defun myfuncall (var fun) 
  (funcall ((cond ((equal fun ":inc") first) 
                  ((equal fun ":res") second) 
                  ((equal fun ":dec") third)) 
            var)))
```

but there's the error

```
While compiling MYFUNCALL :
In the form (#1=(COND ((EQUAL FUN ":inc") FIRST)
                      ((EQUAL FUN ":res") SECOND)
                      ((EQUAL FUN ":dec") THIRD))
             VAR), #1# is not a symbol or lambda expression.
   [Condition of type CCL::COMPILE-TIME-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

Can anyone help me please? How do I make funcall do the right thing for me?

---

Found the solution.

```
(defun make-object () 
  (let ((count 0))
    (lambda (msg)
      (case msg
        ((:inc) (incf count))
        ((:dec) (decf count))
        ((:res) (setq count 0))))))
```

This does what I wanted.

Comment: nice homework job dude XXD

Answer (score 3):

That's almost working.

```
(defun myfuncall (var fun) 
  (funcall ((cond ((equal fun ":inc") first) 
                  ((equal fun ":res") second) 
                  ((equal fun ":dec") third)) 
            var)))
```

There is an extra `( ... )` around the `COND` and the `var` form. You need to remove that.

Also `first` (etc) would be a variable reference. You need to call `(first var)`.

Once you got that working, you may want to write your code differently. What if `MAKE-OBJECT` would return a single function and not a list of three functions. How could that work?

**Next problem**

```
((equal fun ":inc") 'first var)
```

Above makes no sense. You want to call the function `FIRST` on the result of `var`. This then would return a function, which then gets called via `FUNCALL`.

Comment: Yes that's right. Don't I want to do that? I want to make `(funcall a :inc)` work like `(funcall (first a))`.

Comment: @user2553444: Yes, `(first a)` is a valid function call. `'first var` is nothing valid.